# 70s British TV show about 3 people who gained telepathic abilities and solved mysteries

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a TV show, it seems to me it was in the 70's or before, and it was about I think three people who had somehow gained the ability to talk mind to mind. It was British, and they solved mysteries or action stuff, like James Bond. Serious, not comedy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### [*The Champions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Champions) (1968 - 1969)

> Agents Craig Stirling, Sharron Macready and Richard Barrett work for a United Nations law enforcement organization called 'Nemesis', based in Geneva. Barrett is a codebreaker, Stirling a pilot, and Macready a recently widowed scientist and doctor.
>
> During their first mission as a team, their plane crashes in the Himalayas. They are rescued by an advanced civilization living secretly in the mountains of Tibet, who save their lives, granting them enhanced abilities, including extrasensory powers to communicate with one another over distances (telepathy) and to foresee events (precognition), enhanced versions of the ordinary five senses, and intellectual and physical abilities reaching the fullest extent of human capabilities.

Answer (score 24):

Might it be *[The Champions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Champions)* (1968-1969)?

[image: Title card for The Champions]

> Agents Craig Stirling, Sharron Macready and Richard Barrett work for a United Nations law enforcement organization called 'Nemesis', based in Geneva. Barrett is a codebreaker, Stirling a pilot, and Macready a recently widowed scientist and doctor.
>
> During their first mission as a team, their plane crashes in the Himalayas. They are rescued by an advanced civilization living secretly in the mountains of Tibet, who save their lives, granting them enhanced abilities, including extrasensory powers to communicate with one another over distances (telepathy) and to foresee events (precognition), enhanced versions of the ordinary five senses, and intellectual and physical abilities reaching the fullest extent of human capabilities.
>
> Many stories feature unusual villains, such as fascist regimes from unspecified South American countries, Nazis (a common theme of ITC 1960s and 1970s TV, in part owing to both the writers and the domestic audience having been of the war generation) or the Chinese. The villains' schemes often threaten world peace; Nemesis' brief is international, so the agents deal with threats transcending national interests. The main characters have to learn the use of their new powers as they go along, keeping what they discover secret from friend and foe alike. Each episode begins with a close-up shot of a map, showing the region in which the story is to take place, followed by a teaser sometimes prefaced by stock footage; this is followed by the title sequence. Immediately following that is a post-title vignette, in which one or more of the Champions demonstrates exceptional mental or physical abilities, often astonishing or humiliating others. In one example Stirling participates in a sharpshooting contest. In another, Macready's car is blocked in, two laughing passing drunks try to lift it out but she goes round to the other side and pulls it out of the parking space one-handed. Paradoxically, the narration during these often-public demonstrations usually mentions the need to keep the powers a secret.
>
> The only other series regular is the Champions' boss, Tremayne. He does not know that his agents have special abilities, although he does ask innocent questions about just how on their missions they managed to carry out certain tasks about which their reports were vague.

### Opening Credits

It was the first result for me for the query of `70s detective show telepathy`

Comment: I'd forgotten that rather funky, swinging, jazz intro music!

Answer (score 7):

It probably is the one mentioned in the other replies, but just in case, I remember a British show with a similar premise (although less 007-y and more X-Men-y) called [The Tomorrow People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomorrow_People) (1973-1979)

Comment: I went and looked at that, and at the modern remake. It is very interesting the different takes between the two programs: the first one being more 'kid' like, and the second one very teenage angsty.